# how to code inner html for view in Controller mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have mvc project and I want to code for inner html in Controller. In asp.net web forms we do :
   **in design**

```
  <div id = "DivDynamic" runat ="server" >
  </div><br>
```

**in source code**

```
  DivDynamic.InnerHtml = "<div id ="div1"> <h1> Its Heading </h1> </div>"
```

How can i code for inner html of a view in Controller in MVC 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

there is a lot of possible solutions ,
In the controller :

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["myInnerHtml"] = "<div id =\"div1\"> <h1> Its Heading </h1> </div>";
            return View();
        }
```

In the view :

```
<div id = "DivDynamic" >
        @(new HtmlString(ViewData["myInnerHtml"].ToString()))
</div>
```

Ofc you have to check whether ViewData["myInnerHtml"] is null or not